Is it possible to create a stacked column chart in Google Data Studio that isn't additive?
I have air quality data for a school over the course of a month. I would like to display min and max values for air quality for a given day. I can accomplish this with a stacked column chart, but the top of the column will correspond to the min + max rather than just the max value.
I created a calculated field New_Max which subtracted the min from the max. This resulted in the desired height for the column, but when you hover over it, it will display the new calculated value rather than the original max value (obviously).
Is there a way to accomplish this that would still allow for the correct value to show up when you hover over the bar? Or is there an alternate chart that I should try? Any advice is appreciated.

Looker studio is a data visual, the mouse overs will always show the metrics in the graph. If you use power bi or tableau they will allow you to use tool tips to add the data or if you stick with looker studio and you want to show max and min for a day I would suggest that you use a line chart or a boxplot graph 
